# Matches two line immediately following the target line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28758.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28759.gif: 98.92%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28760.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28761.gif: 98.54%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28762.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28763.gif: 98.85%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28764.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28765.gif: 99.91%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28766.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28767.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28768.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28834.gif: 100.00%
tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28835.gif: 100.00%
```

The following regex bookmarks all lines that include a **percentage number under 100.00%**:

```
\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\b%
```

Now I need a regex that bookmarks all lines including a percentage number under 100.00% and two lines after the target line

The following regex can bookmark my target lines and just one line after them:

```
(?-s)(^.+\R?)\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\b%(?:\R^.+)?
```

I tried following regex but I failed:

```
(?-s)(^.+\R?)\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\b%(?:\R^.+)?(?:\R^.+)
```

where is my regex problem?

Comment: Also this will fail to scan percents less than 10% unless they have a leading zero.  Change your first `\d{2}` to `\d{1,2}` to scan one OR two leading digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your regex consumes the lines has percentage lower than `100.00%`.

```
unmatched    tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28758.gif: 100.00%
matched      tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28759.gif: 98.92%
consumed     tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28760.gif: 100.00%
consumed     tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28761.gif: 98.54%
unmatched    tttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 28762.gif: 100.00%
```

Notice the 4th line didn't match because your regex consumed it due to the *"two lines after the target line"* rule.

There are two ways to fix it.

### 1. Put the *"two lines after the target line"* rule in a positive lookahead

This way the 2 lines after the target line will still be matched and back-referenced but not consumed. But it creates overlapped matches.

[`(?-s)(^.+\R?)\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\b%(?=((?:\R^.+){2}))`](https://regex101.com/r/HDnupD/1)

### 2. Match *"two lines after the target line"* but excludes lines that below `100.00%`

This way it will matches the next 0 to 2 lines, depends on the percentages of these lines.

[`(?-s)(^.+\R?)\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\b%(?:\R^(?!.*\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\b%).+){0,2}`](https://regex101.com/r/ZL7eZu/1)

Depends on your needs, these two should work for most of your cases.